# Extension in Swift with CoreMedia data types

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avfoundation, core-media

Since yesterday I though I understand how to write extensions in Swift but now I'm not really sure. I have simple extension for CMTimebase class.

```
extension CMTimebase {

    class func instance(withMasterClock masterClock: CMClock) -> CMTimebase {
        var timebase: CMTimebase? = nil
        CMTimebaseCreateWithMasterClock(kCFAllocatorDefault, masterClock, &timebase)
        return timebase!
    }

    var rate: Float64 {
        set {
            CMTimebaseSetRate(self, rate)
            print(self)
        }
        get {
            return CMTimebaseGetRate(self)
        }
    }

    var seconds: Float64 {
        return CMTimeGetSeconds(CMTimebaseGetTime(self))
    }

}
```

In my code I'm using it like that:

```
let timebase = CMTimebase.instance(withMasterClock:captureSession.masterClock)
timebase.rate = 1.0
```

And I wonder why this is not working because when I do print(timebase) the rate is set to 0.0 after invocation. What is really funny when I invoke:

```
CMTimebaseSetRate(timebase, 1.0)
```

Then rate is set to 1.0 as expected. I think the problem is not related only to CoreMedia or maybe I don't understand some fundamental concepts behind extension. Please help if You know how to correct my extension. I'm trying to target Swift 3.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. It's really stupid error from my side. I need break. There is a typo in extension. It should be instead of rate, newValue.

```
var rate: Float64 {
    set {
        // CMTimebaseSetRate(self, rate)
        // Line below is correct
        CMTimebaseSetRate(self, newValue)
    }
    get {
        return CMTimebaseGetRate(self)
    }
}
```